# FALSE OR NULL doesn't work in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

According to the Hive [language manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-LogicalOperators), `FALSE OR NULL` should evaluate to `NULL`, but I get

```
FAILED: ClassCastException org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableVoidObjectInspector cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.BooleanObjectInspector
```

I can work around this using `IF()`, but why does this not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a or b from (select cast (null as  boolean) as a, false as b from test) x;
```

OK

_c0

NULL

Where test is a dummy table.

Comment: That's a shame you need to cast it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

According manual you have attached "FALSE OR NULL is NULL" not FALSE.

Comment: sorry, that was a typo on my part. But the point is that it won't evaluate it at all because I get the error mentioned.